# if and else without braces

Tags: c++, if-statement

I expect the following code to compile.  Clang and VC++ both give me an error on the line with `else`.

```
void MyFunction(std::int32_t& error)
{
   std::int32_t variable = 0;
   if(GetSomething())
      error = EOK;
   else
      error = ERROR;
}
```

If I put curly braces around `error = EOK;`, then it compiles.  Why does VC++ say:

> illegal else without matching if

?

---

My full code is below, replacing std::uint32_t with a typedef.  It still gives the same error in VC++.

```
using sint32 = int;

#define ERROR 5;
#define EOK 0;

bool GetSomething();

void MyFunction(sint32& error)
{
   sint32 variable = 0;
   if (GetSomething())
      error = EOK;
   else
      error = ERROR;
}
```

Comment: I smell a macro rat.

Comment: whats EOK (or GetSomething )? maybe its some weired  macro definition

Comment: @Graznarak post the full source, including any macros you've defined, because this source by itself compiles for me

Comment: @T.W.R.Cole: It couldn't compile for you without definitions for `std`, `int32_t`, `GetSomething`, `EOK`, and `ERROR`.

Comment: @Keith Correct, I had to make them up.

Comment: This is one of the many examples of why one should not use macros.

Comment: @bames53 And even more importantly, an example of why you should be using braces around if-else controlled statements...

Comment: @silvo: It is a broken macro definition, and has _nothing_ to do with braces being required. You would get a complilation error here from `error = GetSomething() ? EOK : ERROR;` as well ,and there is no way that putting braces into that would help.

Comment: And most importantly of all, an example of why you should POST A TESTCASE from the get-go.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If your definition of EOK is as follows:

`#define EOK 0;`

then it would cause this type of error, because it forcibly terminates the if-statement before the else is reached, making it an else without a matching if.  The compiler sees this code after macro replacement:

```
if(GetSomething())
    error = 0;;
else
```

Comment: better yet use a constant not a macro!

Comment: Ugh, semicolon-terminated macros. Pure evil.

Comment: Reason #245 why control statements without braces are just *asking* for trouble...

Comment: Generally speaking, you can debug pre-processor issues by inspecting the pre-processed file explicitely - in VC, use `CL /P` or `/E`.

@sapi: You could still be foiled by `#define EOK 0}` - though it's much less likely.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a possible fix:

```
enum
{
    EOK = 0,
    ERROR = 5
};
```

Note that all identifiers starting with `E` followed by either another uppercase letter or a number are reserved for use as macro names by `<cerrno>`, so to avoid name clashes consider using a different naming convention for your errors.

Comment: Better make that a class enum for nicer name spacing, also then it wouldn't have to start with E all the time :D

Answer (score 0):

To be implest and more efficient, you can do :

```
error = (GetSomething()) ? 0 : 5 ;
```

And if you want to  with enum as Matt say , it become :

```
error = (GetSomething()) ? enum.EOK : enum.ERROR ;
```

Comment: * error = (GetSomething()) ? enum.EOK : enum.ERROR ;

Comment: I dispute your claim that this is more efficient. The compiler should generate the same code.

Comment: Sebastian , one line of code is easier for the compiler and also for the developer (and also as a complexity side ;) )

Comment: One line of code is not easier for the developer - it depends on how complicated the line is. It definitely is not easier for the compiler - the compiler parses it into a tree either way and the optimizer and code generator work with that, if not an even more heavily processed form.